# Multiple domains serving independent content with Firebase hosting and Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I'm designing and building a web app in which users will upload a static HTML template file. My system will parse their template and create JavaScript code for their individual purpose.

I want each use to have their own namespace, so ideally the endpoints would look something like this

```
user1.domain.com/index.html
user1.domain.com/code.js

user2.domain.com
user2.domain.com/code.js

...
```

It's not possible to programmatically write static files to Firebase hosting, so I envisaged having a Cloud Function that would inspect the HTTP host and serve up the appropriate files. User 1's `index.html` template file would be stored in Firebase Storage in its own sub-space and User 2's in a similar manner.

The end goal is to have `www.userone.com` and `www.usertwo.com` (my customers chosen domains) mapped to `user1.domain.com` and `user2.domain.com` respectively, but I could achieve this using an external CDN proxying requests.

In order for the above solution to work I would need to manually add domains to my Firebase project (using the Firebase control panel) as each user participates in my app. I expecting around 200 customers total.

I could use `staging.domain.com/user-{n}` and then I would only have to configure a single domain for my Firebase project. However, this would force users to have to use relative links to their content within their template. Also, they would have access to other users content i.e. `user-1/index.html` could access `../user-2/code.js` which isn't a security risk but invites more error prone idiocies from users.

Is there a way to configure the hosting to map `*.domain.com` to a single Cloud Function, or at least `user1.domain.com`, `user2...` manually?

If not, can the above scenario be achieved using Google Cloud Infrastructure? (My concern is there is an undocumented limit to the number of domains that can be attached to a single project.)

Comment: it's possible now. https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites

Comment: In general, Firebase Hosting is not presently well-suited to offering a multi-domain multi-tenant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to configure the hosting to map *.domain.com to a single Cloud Function, or at least  user1.domain.com, user2... manually?

You can map multiple domains to a Firebase Hosting project. But each domain will serve the exact same content.

There is no way to configure Firebase Hosting to serve different content for different domains mapped to the same project.

Also see:

- [Firebase hosting with multiple directories at multiple domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43581735/firebase-hosting-with-multiple-directories-at-multiple-domains)
- [Firebase hosting: Serve different pages from different custom domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44047865/firebase-hosting-serve-different-pages-from-different-custom-domains)
- [Multiple domains with the same application running firebase as the backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831891/multiple-domains-with-the-same-application-running-firebase-as-the-backend)
- [How do I make a custom subdomain on Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147602/how-do-i-make-a-custom-subdomain-on-firebase)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have multiple sites on one firebase project serving different content now.

here's the example of `firebase.json`

```
{
  "hosting": [ {
      "target": "blog", // "blog" is the applied target-name for the Hosting site myapp-blog.
      "public": "blog/dist"
    },
    {
      "target": "app", // "app" is the applied target-name for the Hosting site myapp-app.
      "public": "app/dist",
      "rewrites": [...] // You can define specific hosting configurations for each site.
    }
  ]
}
```

Please visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites for more info

Comment: Can you use `app` for all `/**` requests and forward `/blog` to `blog`??